# android volley doesn't pass parameters

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a register activity within my android application, and using android volley I call to a PHP file on the server.

After entering details and pressing enter the following response is recieved.

```
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): Register Response: <br />
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>D:\www\students\project\register.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): <br />
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in <b>D:\www\students\project\register.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): <br />
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: dob in <b>D:\www\students\project\register.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): <br />
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: gender in <b>D:\www\students\project\register.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): <br />
02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in <b>D:\www\students\project\register.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />

02-15 12:59:09.939: D/RegisterActivity(377): {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required Parameters (name, email, gender, dob, password) missing"}
```

So obviously the result means nothing is being passed.

So here is my register activity where, using volley, the request is made.

```
private void registerUser(final String name, final String email, final String dob, final String gender, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq =  new StringRequest(Method.POST,ApplicationServicesConfig.Register_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String dob = user.getString("dob");
                        String gender = user.getString("gender");
                        String created_at = user.getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, dob, gender, created_at);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegisterActivity.this,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("dob", dob);
                params.put("gender", gender);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }      

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Authorization", "Basic Z2FycmV0dGg6ZnJBc3Rpbmc0");
                return params;
            }
        };
        Log.d(TAG, "STRING REQUEST: " + strReq.getUrl());
        // Adding request to request queue
        ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

The map, maps all of the correct parameters to the URL, as far as I can tell.

Normally I do it using HTTP requests but read that volley is a much cleaner way. 
Anyway I also called the url directly with the parameters passed on the end as usual
e.g ?name=bob&age etc etc

Is there a way you can print out the url volley calls, or the params it adds?

Thanks

EDIT PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 */
require_once 'helpers/db_functions.php';
$db = new db_functions();

$response = array("error" => FALSE);
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$dob = $_GET['dob'];
$gender = $_GET['gender'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
$string = $name + $email + $dob + $gender + $password;
json_encode($string);

if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['dob']) && isset($_GET['gender']) && isset($_GET['password'])){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $dob = $_GET['dob'];
    $gender = $_GET['gender'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];

    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)){
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User email already exists = " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    }else{
        $user = $db->insertUser($name,$email,$gender,$dob,$password);
        if ($user){
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $repsonse["user"]["id"] = $user["id"];
            $repsonse["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $repsonse["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $repsonse["user"]["dob"] = $user["dob"];
            $repsonse["user"]["gender"] = $user["gender"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else{
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Problem when registering user";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
}else{
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required Parameters (name, email, gender, dob, password) missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}



?>
```

Comment: Have you tested your PHP page alone if it works or not?

Comment: need to see url of web service

Comment: Yes it works, as I mentioned above (albeit not clearly) I called the .php page with the parameters on the end like ?name=bob&age=22 and it worked fine. @Sharj

Comment: donot pass value from params please added in Url and call the Volley request Like    www.localhost/index.php?name=bob&age=22

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar, Its not the good approach. getParams purpose is to send the url paramters then why to use the manual addition in url

Comment: try to remove getHeaders and then see what happens?

Comment: i know that but we have different type of wen service now a day like same are working from SOAP And RESTFUL and also some are taking data from query-sting and some are taking jsonobjct  so i m saying is you make web service with query-string so its mandatory to call from URL

Comment: You should of course post your php script.

Comment: Have you checked if `getParams() ` is called?

Comment: `with the parameters on the end like ?name=bob&age=22`. That would be a GET request. But you instruct Volley to do a POST request. So show your php script so we can check which method is used.

Comment: @greenapps updated question for you to see php

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You have posted the php file. You can clearly see that it expects a GET method. So instruct Volley to do a GET request instead of a POST request now..

Comment: Updated the line `StringRequest strReq =  new StringRequest(Method.POST,ApplicationServicesConfig.Register_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {`  and still received the response   `02-15 14:47:31.968: D/LoginActivity(625): Login Response: {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required information (email, password) are missing!"}`@greenapps

Comment: Which line of yout php script is pruduciing that error in json text?

Comment: The else statement from the if which checks whether the parameters are there `}else{
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required Parameters (name, email, gender, dob, password) missing";
    echo json_encode($response);` @greenapps

Comment: Well required information for two parameters is something different as required parameters missing and mentioning five. So very strange. Thats why i asked. That statement cannot produce that result as everybody can see. So report better please.

Comment: Oh sorry, I gave the response for register rather than login. Login is the same `}else{ $response["error"] = TRUE; $response["error_msg"] = "Required Parameters (name, email) missing"; echo json_encode($response);` The PHP doesn't seem to be the problem because when I call from browser with parameters required added on the end it works fine. I changed the POST to GET within the volley segment.@greenapps

Comment: In your php script put only the statement `var_dump ($_GET);`. Read the result in your client. Its no json what you get so dont try to make json objects of it. Just display/log the result and tell us.

Comment: If you have two php scripts then which code did you post and about which one are we talking?

Comment: That i already told you. I told you what you had to do to see it.

Comment: No not Eclipse. What has Eclipse to do with this. Your Android client app of course. You can show the result in your app. Or if the app logs it in Eclipse. Well thats indeed Eclipse...

Comment: I was talking about the debug messages within logcat, in eclipse

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());`. Thats where i am talking about.

Comment: `02-16 08:05:46.358: D/LoginActivity(890): Login Response: array(0) {
02-16 08:05:46.358: D/LoginActivity(890): }`

Comment: `I was talking about the debug messages within logcat, in eclipse`. But var_dump will not be printed there of course. Your app can read it. Then your app has it as the response. If your app then logs the respones (as your app does) you can see the response in the logcat. But please dont suggest that var_dump gets pinted in the logcat. No it will not.

Comment: Well an empty array. Not a single parameter received. Now try to call it from your browser again and see what you receive.

Comment: `array(2) { ["name"]=> string(7) "barry" ["email"]=> string(7) "h@h.com" } ` from calling `http://...../project/helper/login.php?name=barry&email=h@h.com`

Comment: So what is your conclusion?

Comment: You were so `friendly` never to answer my question: `Have you checked if getParams() is called? `.

Comment: My conclusion is that the `getParams()` override of the volley implementation isn't adding the parameters - therefore none are being passed. I knew from the beginning that nothing was being passed, as getParams isn't called.

Comment: Well then you should have told that long time ago as now you wasted my time. I even asked you so and you didnt answer.

Comment: It says in my description of the question `So obviously the result means nothing is being passed.` and `The map, maps all of the correct parameters to the URL, as far as I can tell.` My question was `Is there a way you can print out the url volley calls, or the params it adds?`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that my syntax of `StringRequest` is wrong,

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest( API.BOOKING_COMPLETE_API, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

here first parameter `StringRequest.Method.POST` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script should test `isset( $_POST['variable'] )`, not `$_GET[]` since you changed method to `POST`.